# How can I see if this fsck operation corrected any filesystem errors?

Tags: filesystems, fsck, e2fsck

After doing a fsck on a filesystem, someone asked me if the fsck resolved any problems. I'm not sure how to interprete the following results. Do you see anything important to notice ?

```
root@server1> fsck -fyv /donnees
fsck 1.35 (28-Feb-2004)
e2fsck 1.35 (28-Feb-2004)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

1468099 inodes used (0%)
114532 non-contiguous inodes (7.8%)
# of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 456970/35761/8
249447788 blocks used (77%)
0 bad blocks
19 large files

1176399 regular files
291142 directories
0 character device files
0 block device files
140 fifos
2 links
407 symbolic links (403 fast symbolic links)
2 sockets
--------
1468092 files
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to determine whether this particular `fsck` operation corrected any errors would have been to check its [exit code](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/e2fsck.8.html#EXIT_CODE): `e2fsck` sets bit 1 of its exit code if it corrected errors, and bit 2 if it corrected errors requiring a reboot (*i.e.* on a mounted file system).

You can also determine that `e2fsck` didn’t make any change here, because the output doesn’t mention

```
***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
```

which `e2fsck` outputs if it made any changes (unless the `-p` option was specified).